# Sticky page navigation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to implement sticky navigation (with a set of buttons, that on click moves you to exact section). I've mostly implemented all the logic, but there is a problem with connecting everything together.

Cases:

- you're able to click button and be moved to section (after click button should change its className to active),
- on scroll - you're scrolling to section and it's getting active className in navigation once you entered the section

My solution works fine (at some point), but the timeout is problematic. If I click a section and i will be moved to another section but at the same time i click another section then active className will be "flashing".

is there anything that can be done here? I would appreciate comments on the code

sorry for the readability of the code, I know it can be done much better (in terms of quality and readability), I did it quickly to illustrate this example (in fact, the structure is more complicated, but it reflects it 100%)

code: https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-dew-tev29r?file=/src/App.js
I was inspired by the navigation behavior on mui.com (eg. https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api)